# Checking for any collisions between rectangles in a collection

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, collision-detection

I'm trying to create a C++ function which controls if N rectangles are collisioning. The N rectangles are in a std::vector. The idea is to compare every element of the vector with others (only one time) to verify if there are collisions. 
I already implemented code to do this, but I am looking for a better, cleaner and more elegant way (I'm a C++ newbie).
My code is:

```
bool areCollisioningNRectangles(std::vector<Rectangle> rect) {
    const unsigned long size = rect.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (areCollisioningTwoRectangles(rect[i], rect[j])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Possible move to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Complexity is O(N^2). How many rectangles do you have? You may need something like a [quadtree](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-use-quadtrees-to-detect-likely-collisions-in-2d-space--gamedev-374).

Comment: I have about 100 rectangles on the screen at the same time. I would like to create a simple engine for a 2d game. I've already read of quadtree. In fact this is the next step I would like to implement. I'm trying to start from basis and then increase the complexity. The approach tried is unit test.